# API FACEBOOK - DOMINIO DE APLICATIVO

Tags: php, api, facebook

Estou tentando usar a API do Facebook para fazer um login. Offline está funcionando, porém, quando coloco online tenho o seguinte problema:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Assim está minhas configurações básicas do app:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: acredito que existe outra area para colocar url ai!

Comment: @Lodi estou tendo esse problema, vc conseguiu resolver ?

Answer (score 0):

Em Configurações na aba Avançado você tem algumas opções a configurar também da uma olhada na imagem abaixo depois tente configurar o seu aplicativo novamente!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: No caso, o que eu teria que colocar?

Comment: bom você tem que configurar tudo, facebook é bem chatinho, mas da uma olhada no gerenciador de domínios, tenta adicionar um e vê se da certo!

Comment: Tentei adicionar, e deu o mesmo erro

Comment: na sua request da uma olhada no link que fica na barra de endereços quando da esse erro vê se a URL que está indo é a correta!